# accessing android os root files

Tags: android, c, operating-system, controls

i have the following doubt:

i have read that android os is based on linux, and i imagine it may have the same structure that ubuntu (in terms of file configurations: /root, /dev, etc).
so, is it possible to run an application written in C in android? just as it is possible to do in ubuntu? if so, how can i do that?

also, how can i get access to the root files through an android application (written in java)? and how to get access to the behavior of the os (in terms of interruptions for example)?

thanks in advance for your answers.

gus

Comment: I support this question, but why would you want to?

Comment: if you want to develop an antivirus or something similar, and also to have higher control of the machine just like in ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic answer: Running a C app on Android isn't supported, except through the Native Development Kit (NDK).

You can't get access to the root files except by rooting a phone.

You can get access to some OS behavior through the API. Basically, if it's not part of the API, you can't access it.

The Android OS is *based* on Linux, but it's an OS, not a windowing server like X or a desktop environment like Gnome or KDE.

Comment: thanks for the answer, now i'm understanding it better. but now i have the following doubts: 1. when you use the app to add contacts (such phone numbers, for example), where is that info saved in the phone? can i access to that location? if so, how?; 2. is it possible to access the information being insert in an application? for example: suppose that an app is running and the user inserts some information in a field of the app, is it possible to access that info through another app? (due to they are running in "different" virtual machines). thanks again, gus.

Answer (score 0):

You may run `C and C++` code on android using NDK. You may use also `QT` framework. But code is runing in virtual machine named Davlik. Android have root acount , but it is default not available for user. Therefore, access to directory is dependend for `chmod`.

If you would like read about access to low level in android:
http://www.phrack.org/issues.html?issue=68&id=6

And about architecture this system:
https://developer.android.com/guide/basics/what-is-android.html

Comment: thanks for the answer, very usefull. but digging a little more the structure of android os, now i have the following doubts: 1. when you use the app to add contacts (such phone numbers, for example), where is that info saved in the phone? can i access to that location? if so, how?; 2. is it possible to access the information being insert in an application? for example: suppose that an app is running and the user inserts some information in a field of the app, is it possible to access that info through another app? (due to they are running in "different" virtual machines). thanks again, gus.

Comment: 1. Contact and orther data is stored in `SQLite db` 2. In VM application have other own process. 2. In linux access to other proces it possible when you use `ptrace`. In android maybe by similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can run programs using [`Runtime.exec`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29). As an example, you can see [Terminal IDE](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spartacusrex.spartacuside&hl=en) which runs many different programs including ssh, vim and bash. It's also open source so you can learn from the [code](http://code.google.com/p/terminal-ide/). You will probably have to include the executable as a resource or asset and then copy to a local directory, grant execute permissions, then run with `Runtime.exec`. You still have limited user permissions as your app runs under a restricted account unless the device is rooted and you request root access.

Answer (score 0):

an android smartphone/tablet works with an Arm cpu, not a x85. the architecture is different.
but you CAN run a C application in android if you cross compile it for arm linux. or you can use a c compiler inside android device. people ported c compiler to android. you can try C4DROID and in android market. but you can only run compiled program in system memory because of android permissions about sd card.